# How to check if function was not called in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a following script in which i am calling a function from "lib" file. It works fine. But how to implement exception handling so that if i change the function name in the script file or in the "lib" file and function is not called, the script should be terminated.

**Script File:**

```
#!/bin/bash

#Include Functions file
. ./testlibrary.lib
echo "Start"
testFunction
echo "Finish"
```

**LibraryFile:**

```
#!/bin/bash



testFunction(){

    echo "testing begins"

    echo  "testing ends"

}
```

**Note:**

I can't use "set -e" flag so is there any other way to implement this that if my command fails it should terminate the script.

Comment: Why can't you use `set -e`?  You probably should....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see if the function exists beforehand with `typeset`:

```
if [[ -z "$(typeset -f testFunction)" ]] ; then
    echo Cannot find testFunction
    exit
fi
testFunction
```

It's a bit of a kludge but it seems to work okay with my minimal testing to date. You might want to keep an eye out for edge cases however.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
if ! testFunction
then echo "testFunction not found"
     exit
fi
```

as long as the function itself never exits with an error.

Comment: i have tried your approach but it's not working. I think there is something wrong with syntax..

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the function call fails in general, like this:

```
testFunction || exit 1
```

Note that this does not distinguish the case of "function not found" from "function failed."  If you need to do that, do it before calling the function:

```
type -t testFunction >/dev/null || exit 1
testFunction # definitely exists, could still fail but we'll ignore that
```